# python multi volume tar

Tags: python, archive, tar, volume

I'm trying to create multi volume tar file in bzip2 compression. I'm compressing some really big files. What should I do?

This works, except doesn't do multi volume thing:

```
out = tarfile.open('../temp/tarfile_add.tar', mode='w:bz2')
try:
    out.add("gooz/big_dude.avi")
finally:
    out.close()
```

Thanks,
Sep

Comment: What exactly is the "multi volume thing"?

Comment: @Scott it is like spliting big file into smaller files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such thing as a "multi volume tar"; there is nothing in the tar specification regarding spanning tar files. You will need to split the file separately from generating the archive.

Comment: OK, I don't have to make it a tar archive. I just need an archiving method that holds the structure of files and folders and at the same time has error checking bits for multi voluming. Like RAR but Python doesn't seem to have RAR libraries. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

GNU tar has multivolume support. Easily installable on OSX through HomeBrew. I'm not sure if it offers compression, but you could compress the resulting tar files.

As best I can tell, python does not support tar Multivolume.